# tab height is not coming properly in android device

Tags: android

I implemented tablayout but it is not working properly in emulator. The height is not showing properly in device. Can anybody tell me what the problem is?

**this is my layout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 <TabHost 
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black"
        > 
   <RelativeLayout    
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
         <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"  
             android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs" /> 
    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                       /> 
          </RelativeLayout> 
    </TabHost>
    </LinearLayout>
```

this is my java code setting height and width

```
for (int i =0; i<tabWidget.getChildCount(); i++) {
         //tabWidget.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(R.color.black);
          tabWidget.getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height = height;
   tabWidget.getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().width = width;
   RelativeLayout relLayout = (RelativeLayout)tabWidget.getChildAt(i); 
   TextView tv = (TextView)relLayout.getChildAt(1); 
   tv.setTextSize(10.0f);
   tv.setTypeface(myTypeface1);
}
```

Can anybody tell me how to set height and width for tab bar? Give sample code

Thanks

Comment: Why are you setting the width from code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably related to the difference in screen density between the emulator and your device. Check out [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) - you need to get the density of the current device as follows:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
float density = metrics.density;
```

Next, calculate the necessary height and width scaling factor according to the section on density independent pixels on the [Android dev site](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html):

float scaling_factor = density / 160;

Finally, set your widget's height and width appropriately:

```
tabWidget.getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height = int ( height * scaling_factor );
tabWidget.getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().width = int ( width * scaling_factor );
```